# While search each character of a string and change it in emu8086 how to end infinite loop?

Tags: assembly, infinite-loop, x86-16, instructions, emu8086

When compare and change a character of a string to another character, it is not change last character.

But when i change cx to 12 is working but it is stuck infinite loop

```
.model small
.stack 64
.data
        dizi1 db 'bilgisayai'
.code
            mov ax,@data
            mov ds,ax
            mov es,ax

            lea di,dizi1

            mov cx,10
            mov al,'i'
            mov bl,'#'

ara: repne  scasb
            jnz cik
            mov [di-1],bl
            loop ara

cik:        mov ah,4ch
            int 21h
            end
```

i want to change 'i's in the string to '#' but last 'i' doesn't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Don't use `LOOP`

#### What happens when you set `CX=10`  ==>  "Not found"

> 'bilgisayai'

When `scasb` finds the 1st 'i', `CX` is **8** and the `loop` instruction will decrement down to **7**, but continues fine. However for `scasb` your string is now 1 character shorter!

> 'bi ... lgisaya'

When `scasb` finds the 2nd 'i', `CX` is **4** and the `loop` instruction will decrement down to **3**, but continues fine. However for `scasb` your string is again 1 character shorter!

> 'bi ... lgi ... say'

`scasb` will process a further 3 bytes, no longer finds an 'i' and the program exits.

#### What happens when you set `CX=12`  ==>  "Infinite loop"

> 'bilgisayai??'

When `scasb` finds the 1st 'i', `CX` is **10** and the `loop` instruction will decrement down to **9**, but continues fine. However for `scasb` your string is now 1 character shorter!

> 'bi ... lgisayai?'

When `scasb` finds the 2nd 'i', `CX` is **6** and the `loop` instruction will decrement down to **5**, but continues fine. However for `scasb` your string is again 1 character shorter!

> 'bi ... lgi ... sayai'

When `scasb` finds the 3rd 'i', `CX` is **0** and the `loop` instruction will decrement down to **65535** , and continues *'forever'*.

## Solution.

Replace `loop` by next code:

```
  lea  di, dizi1
  mov  cx, 10       ;Length of the string (true length!)
  mov  al, 'i'
  mov  bl, '#'    
ara:
  repne scasb
  jnz  cik
  mov  [di-1], bl
  test cx, cx       ;If CX=0 then SCASB was at end of string
  jnz  ara
cik:
```

Comment: it worked. thank you. actually i found another solution. when i add `h` at the and of the value `cx`, it's working too.